# Populating list with sqlite db

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

How can I populate a list with data from a SQLite database in my Blackberry application?  I can view the list, but I can see only one item which is the last item from my database table in the list. Below is the code:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;

import net.rim.device.api.database.Database;
import net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseFactory;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Row;
import net.rim.device.api.database.Statement;
import net.rim.device.api.io.URI;

class ListFieldScreen extends MainScreen
{

  Database d;

    public ListFieldScreen() 
    {
      final ObjectListField list = new ObjectListField();
                try
                {

                   URI myURI=URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/MyTestDatabase.db");
                   d=DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
                   Statement st=d.createStatement("SELECT eng FROM English");
                   st.prepare();
                   net.rim.device.api.database.Cursor c=st.getCursor();
                   Row r;

                   while(c.next())
                   {

                    r=c.getRow();
                    String w=r.getString(0);
                    String[] t={w};
                        list.set(t); 
                       add(list);                        
                   }


                   st.close();
                   d.close();
                   }
                     catch ( Exception e ) {         
          e.printStackTrace();
                      }                      


    }
    }
```

Comment: because you are creating only one list which is declared as final;

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:
First declare as

```
public Vector tableVector;
public ObjectListField list;
```

and call this below code in separate method;

```
 tableVector=new Vector();//Declare this before the method;
    try
    {
        //Uri creation
        Statement st=LoadingScreen.database.createStatement("YOUR Statement");          
        st.prepare();
        Cursor c = st.getCursor();

        Row r;           
        while(c.next()) 
        {

            r = c.getRow();                
            tableVector.addElement(r.getString(0));
        }
        st.execute();           
        st.close();         
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Exception;
    }
```

After complete this method; show the data as...

```
String ar[]=new String[tableVector.size];
for(int i=0;i<tableVector.size;i++)
{
    ar[i]=tableVector.elementAt(i).toString();
}
list.set(ar);
add(list);
```

Comment: list.set(tableVector.elementAt(i).toString()); This statement shows error .method set cannot be applied to given types

Comment: I changed the code see once. The main thing is I didn't work in ObjectListField up to now. That's why. Now the code is file.

Comment: I replaced ar[tableVector.elementAt(i).toString()];  with        ar[i]= tableVector.elementAt(i).toString(); in your code and now no errors runs fine..but cannot see any list only blank screen

Comment: It is a big topic to know about ObjectListField. So better to use LabelField array to show the data;

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need to specify number of items you want to show in the list - I mean number of ites from db -

Comment: I tried to using String [] arr=new String[50];and i tried list.set(arr)but still not working

Comment: I think its because the string array is overwritten and final data appears may b.but any other solution?